# Как сделать форматированный вывод массива в .txt

Tags: php

Данные:

```
[194] => array(6) {
    ["id"]      => string(3) "195"
    ["text1"]   => string(8) "accounts"
    ["text2"]   => string(2) "hi"
    ["text3"]   => string(7) "1234567"
    ["data"]    => string(19) "2016-01-21 11:06:21"
    ["text4"]   => string(1) "4"
}
[195] => array(6) {
    ["id"]      => string(3) "196"
    ["text1"]   => string(8) "accounts"
    ["test2"]   => string(2) "hi"
    ["text3"]   => string(7) "7654321"
    ["data"]    => string(19) "2016-01-21 11:06:26"
    ["text4"]   => string(1) "0"
}
```

Текущий вывод в tхt-файл таков:

```
194      accounts      hi      1234567      2016-01-21 11:06:21      0
195      accounts      hi      7654321      2016-01-21 11:06:21      4
```

Длина полей, максимальные значения:

```
id = 10
text1 = 15
text2 = 10
text3 = 20
data = 20
text4 = 10
```

**Нужный формат вывода**. Длина текущего id у 195 равна 3 (например, у `1003` будет равна 4).
Т.е. берем максимальное значение поля `id` (10) из него вычитаем текущее значение `id` у "195", которое равняется 3. `10 - 3 = 7`.
Т.о. при записи данной строки нужно сделать 7 отступов от начала строки;
потом сделать 7 отступов от 195 вправо. Т.е. поле `text1 (15) - string(8)` `"accounts"` и т.д

Должно получится нечто вроде:

```
195       accounts        hi             7654321
```

```
// Create connection

$db = mysql_connect($servername, $username, $password);
mysql_select_db($dbname, $db) or die("Could not open: " . mysql_error());
// Run query
$query     = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM . $tablename");
// How match rows selected?
print "Total rows selected: ".mysql_num_rows($query);
// Define a variable as an array
$data = array();
$fp    = fopen($path . $filename, 'w') or die ("Can't close $filename");
// Forming the array
while ($row_select = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
    fputs($fp, implode("      ", $row_select) . "\r\n");
}

fclose($fp) or die("Can't close $filename");    // close file
```

Comment: Как вариант, еще можно использовать csv  формат для совместимости с Excel например. http://php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php, http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 3):

Вычислить максимальные длины значений придётся заранее. А выводить, выравнивая вправо помогут функции `printf()` или [`sprintf()`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.sprintf.php) с форматом, указывающим число позиций. Например, дополняем строки пробелами вправо до 8 позиций:

```
printf('%8s', 'abcdefgh'); // abcdefgh
printf('%8s', 'abc');      //      abc
```

То же для чисел:

```
printf('%8d', 12345678);   // 12345678
printf('%8d', 123);        //      123
printf('%08d', 123);       // 00000123  - тут добиваем нулями
```

В вашем примере, когда уже известны максимальные длины полей, вывод строк в цикле будет примерно такой:

```
while ($row_select = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
    fputs($fp, sprintf(
        "%10d %15s %10s %20s %20s %10s\r\n",
        $row_select['id'],
        $row_select['text1'],
        $row_select['text2'],
        $row_select['text3'],
        $row_select['data'],
        $row_select['text4'],
    ));
}
```